# How to make a variatic method take a single array as the first value of the varargs array?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

Given the variables:

```java
Object[] ab = new Object[] { "a", "b" };
Object[] cd = new Object[] { "c", "d" };
```

When calling the following method:

```java
public static void m(Object... objects) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objects));
}
```

Using:

```java
m(ab, cd);
```

I get the expected output:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3e25a5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@19821f]
```

But when using:

```java
m(ab);
```

I get:

```
[a, b]
```

Since `strings <- ab` and not `strings[0] <- ab`.

How can I *force* the compiler to take the `ab` array as the first value of the `strings` array, and then having the output:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@3e25a5
```

?

Comment: An overload accepting `Object[]` and passing it into `m` might be a workaround here.

Comment: @defaultlocale You can't represent such an overload at the bytecode level since it would result in a duplicate signature.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  thanks for pointing this out. Didn't have a compiler by hand, thus, a silly comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typecast it while passing and you will get what you want -

```
m((Object)ab);
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from as suggested by @Sudhansu. You can define the variables as below so you don't have to bother with casting in method call when passing single array.

```
Object ab = new Object[] { "a", "b" };
Object cd = new Object[] { "c", "d" };
```